# Prove that a particular sequence of functions converge $\mu-$ almost uniformly

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given $\Omega = (0,1)$, $\mathcal{A}$ is the Borel Sigma-Algebra restricted to $\Omega$, and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, let $f(\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega}$ and

$f_n (\omega) = 1$ if $0<\omega < \frac{1}{n}$

$f_n (\omega) = \frac{1}{\omega}$ if $\frac{1}{n} \le \omega < 1$

I have to prove that $f_n$ converges $\mu$-almost uniformly to $f$.

From what I learned in class, I have to show: $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists E_{\epsilon} \in \mathcal{A}, \mu ( E_{\epsilon}^c) < \epsilon \implies f_n \text{ converges uniformly to } f \text{ on } E_{\epsilon}.$$

My idea was to let $E_{\epsilon} = [\epsilon - 0.000000001, 1)$. Then $E_{\epsilon}^c = (0, \epsilon - 0.000000001) \implies \mu ( E_{\epsilon}^c) < \epsilon .$

To prove uniform convergence, I need: $$\forall \delta > 0, \exists N_{\delta} \implies \forall n > N_{\delta}, \forall \omega \in E_{\epsilon}, |f_n (\omega) - f(\omega)| < \delta.$$

Since $E_{\epsilon} = [\epsilon - 0.000000001, 1),$ $\omega \ge \epsilon - 0.000000001$, so if $\epsilon - 0.000000001 \ge \frac{1}{n}$, we get $|f_n (\omega) - f(\omega)| = 0 < \delta.$

This holds for all $n \ge \frac{1}{\epsilon - 0.000000001}$, so we let $N_{\delta} = \frac{1}{\epsilon - 0.000000001}$, proving the almost uniform convergence.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: Why the very specific value $0.000000001$? You need to verify for $\epsilon$ less than this as well

Comment: The 0.000000001 just means that it is barely less than $\epsilon$. In that case, since $E_{\epsilon}^c = (0, \epsilon - 0.000000001 ),$ its Lebesgue measure is $\epsilon - 0.000000001 < \epsilon$. If I didn't include that small quantity, the measure is $\epsilon$ so it doesn't work. But otherwise, does the proof work?

Comment: I will strongly recommend you not use such highly specific numbers, especially since such small terms are supposed to be arbitrary - and $\epsilon-0.00000001$ may well end up $0$, or negative, damaging any argument. Just set, say, $\epsilon/2$, or something like this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the configuration of uniform convergence with the $\sup$ distance. Consider the partition $E^c_m=(0,1/m),E_m=[1/m,1)$ for $m \in \mathbb{N}$. We have that on $E^c_m$ the convergence is not uniform, but on $E_m$ it is as we have $\sup_{\omega \in E_m}|f_n(\omega)-f(\omega)|=(m-1)\mathbf{1}_{\{n:n<m\}}(n)\stackrel{n \to \infty}{\to}0$. Notice this is valid for all $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $\mu((0,1/m))=1/m$, for arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ we can choose $m>1/\varepsilon$ and the condition is satisfied.